# Perl: Matching hash keys to a regular expression

Tags: perl, hash

I'm wondering if Perl has a built-in way to check for the existence of a hash element with a key matching a particular regex. For example:

```
my %h = ( 'twelve' => 12, 'thirteen' => 13, 'fourteen' => 14 );
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to do this:

```
print "We have 12\n" if exists $h{twelve};
print "We have some teens\n" if exists $h{/.*teen$/};
```

Comment: If you have the `teen$` the `.*` is superfluous.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [smart match operator](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlsyn#Smart_matching_in_detail) does this (available since Perl v5.10).

```
$a      $b        Type of Match Implied    Matching Code
======  =====     =====================    =============
...
Regex   Hash      hash key grep            grep /$a/, keys %$b
...
```

Sample usage:

```
# print if any key in %h ends in "teen"
print "We have some teens\n" if /.*teen$/ ~~ %h;
```

Comment: Note that this operator has been in a state of flux and has been deemed "experimental" as of Perl 5.18 (emitting warnings anywhere it's used). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927024/perl-5-20-and-the-fate-of-smartmatch-and-given-when/

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the other answers here you can also do this with perl's grep:

```
print "We have some teens\n" if grep {/.*teen/} keys %h;
```

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, it's called:

```
use List::Util qw<first>;

# Your regex does not compile perhaps you mean /teen$/
my $value = $hash{ ( first { m/teen/ } keys %hash ) || '' };
```

(Before smart match, that is. See mob's answer for smart match.)

You could also sort the keys:

```
my $value = $hash{ ( first { m/teen/ } sort keys %hash ) || '' };
```

I would freeze this into an "operation":

```
use Scalar::Util qw<reftype>;

sub values_for_keys_like (\[%$]$) {
    my $ref = reftype( $_[0] ) eq 'HASH' ? $_[0] : $$_[0];
    return unless my @keys = keys %$ref;

    my $regex = shift;
    # allow strings
    $regex    = qr/$regex/ unless my $typ = ref( $regex );
    # allow regex or just plain ol' filter functions.
    my $test  = $typ eq 'CODE' ? $regex : sub { return unless m/$regex/; 1 };

    if ( wantarray ) { 
        return unless my @k = grep { defined $test->( $_ ) } @keys;
        return @$ref{ @k };
    }
    else {
        return unless my $key = first { defined $test->( $_ ) } @keys;
        return $ref->{ $key };
    }
}
```

And you could use it like so:

```
my $key = values_for_keys_like( %hash => qr/teen/ );
```

Or

```
my $key = values_for_keys_like( $base->{level_two}{level_three} => qr/teen/ );
```

Comment: `sort`? Eh? There's no reason to sort the keys if you're just testing for whether a match exists. Just `first { m/teen$/ } keys %hash` is better.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman: As usual in SO, there is the general question and there is the particular application the user is looking for. The general question is "Matching hash keys to regular expression". `first` is an implementation of `any` concept--but contains other implications: first *how?* I tend to like to cover more than the specific application.

Comment: I fail to see *any* situation in which sorting is applicable to the question "is there a match?". Whether a match exists or not is independent of order, thus order is irrelevant. The sole effect of sorting is to impose a specific order, but order is irrelevant, so sorting just uses up resources (time/memory) for no purpose. The question here is asking about the `any` concept, independent of order; `first` is appropriate solely because `List::Util` doesn't provide an `any` function.

Answer (score 4):

There's no built-in way, but there's [`Tie::Hash::Regex`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aHash%3a%3aRegex) on CPAN.