# How to modify the value if the key is matched with regexp in perl hash?

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I have a hash named `%coins`.
I am to trying to modify the value of the hash if the key of the hash matches with some string.
I tried the following code, but couldn't succeed. It is creating new key instead of modifying the existing key's value.

Please help

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %coins;
%coins = ( "abc" , 1,
          "mno pqr" , 2,
          "xyz",  3 );

print Dumper \%coins;

if(grep {/mno/} keys %coins)
{
    print"matched \n";
    $coins{$_} = s/$coins{$_}/new_val/g;
}

print Dumper \%coins;
```

Comment: see http://www.zentut.com/perl-tutorial/perl-hash/#Modifying_value_of_a_hash_element

Comment: Related: [Perl: Matching hash keys to a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182399/perl-matching-hash-keys-to-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, change

```
if(grep {/mno/} keys %coins)
{
    ...
}
```

to

```
for(grep {/mno/} keys %coins)
{
    ...
}
```

As for the value, you want to

```
( my $new_val = $_ ) =~ s/mno/new_value/g;
$coins{$_} = $new_val;
```

or

```
$coins{$_} = $_ =~ s/mno/new_value/gr;    # Perl 5.14+
```

Comment: If I do so, the output is `$VAR1 = {
          'mno pqr' => 2,
          'abc' => 1,
          'xyz' => 3
        };
matched
$VAR1 = {
          'mno pqr' => '',
          'abc' => 1,
          'xyz' => 3
        };
`
But after replacing, It should have been `'mno pqr' => new_value pqr`

Comment: The value is completed replaced as `new_val`. Where as it should have been `new_val pqr`

Comment: For example (in the above code): If the matched key is "mno pqr" then I want to have the value of "mno pqr" as "new_value pqr"

Comment: wow, that's a weird thing to do. Fixed that bug too. Guru's answer is not as bad as I thought it was. (It just doesn't handle multiple instances of "mno", which may or may not be a problem.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That fixes handling of multiple instances of "mno".

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %coins;
%coins = ( "abc" , 1,
          "mno pqr" , 2,
          "xyz",  3 );

print Dumper \%coins;

my $newval=9;
foreach my $k (keys%coins){
        $coins{$k}=$1.$newval.$2 if ($k =~/(.*)mno(.*)/);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I wanted to replace the value of `mno pqr` (i.e 2) with `9 pqr`.

Comment: OK. To make it clear: I want to replace the value of the matched key with the value same as the key but by replacing matched content in key. 
Pheww.. its getting more confused.. For example (in the above code): If the matched key is "mno pqr" then I want to have the value of "mno pqr" as "new_value pqr".

Comment: What if the key is `ghi mno pqr`? The value after modification will be `9 pqr`. It should have been `ghi 9 pqr`.....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23083/discussion-between-guru-and-ss-hegde)