# What are the conditions under which one can use a 'when' statement in Perl 5?

Tags: perl, for-loop, foreach

Documentation seems sparse regarding `when` statements outside of `given` blocks. It is said the `when` can be used when a 'topic' has been set, but when exactly is a topic considered set? Consider these cases:

```
for (@arr) {
  when { }
}
```

Seems this is the default, basic case, <s>but I couldn't get even this working on my perl 5.14.2 - `$ perl -Mfeature=switch -e 'foreach (qw(a b c)) { when (/a/) {print 'boom'} }'` prints nothing. What am I doing wrong?</s> Turned out this was just another bash quoting issue.

```
for my $elem (@arr) {
  when { }
}
```

Would this work? Will $elem automatically become the topic for `when` to use?

```
for (@arr) {
  $_ = some_expression($_);
  when { }
}
```

Would this work? Can the topic be set inside the loop?

Also, is there any difference when each of the above code segments uses `foreach` instead of `for`?

Basically, I'm very unclear on the topic of topics, so please enlighten me.

Answer (score 7):

It's a shell command construction error.

```
perl -Mfeature=switch -e 'foreach (qw(a b c)) { when (/a/) {print 'boom'} }'
```

should be

```
perl -Mfeature=switch -e 'foreach (qw(a b c)) { when (/a/) {print '\''boom'\''} }'
```

We can switch to double quotes to simplify

```
perl -Mfeature=switch -le'foreach (qw(a b c)) { when (/a/) {print "boom"} }'
```

And we can simplify further

```
perl -E'for (qw(a b c)) { when (/a/) { say "boom" } }'
```

Keywords `for` and `foreach` are one and the same to Perl.

Note that 5.18 marked `given` and `when` as experimental. It won't go away, but it will change. I explain what's going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16930588/589924).

---

No, `when` doesn't use `$elem`; it always uses `$_`.

---

Yes, you can change `$_` inside of `for` or `given` if you so desire. Note that foreach loops aliase their topic to the element being visited, so changing one changes the other.

```
my @x = qw( abc def );
for (@x) { $_ = uc($_); }
say @x;  # ABCDEF
```

Comment: I always go wrong with the quotes, thanks. 

Thanks for the link to your other answer, that and the links from there helped understand the status better. 

I have a weird case with this one: `perl -E '@arr = qw(a b c); foreach $x (@arr) { $_=$x; $_++; when (/b/) {print $x} }'`
It prints a as expected, but then seems to die with the error "Can't use when() outside a topicalizer at -e line 1.". The same code runs without error (but printing nothing) if I remove the two lines with $_. Could you explain what's going on here?

Comment: @sundar, The problem isn't the choice of quotes. The problem is that you didn't escape them properly. See update.

Comment: this syntax for escaping ' is new and useful to me, thanks. 
regarding the topicalization, that's why I mentioned that "the same code runs without error if I remove the two lines with $_". It seems that any for/foreach loop is treated as a topicalizer, even for SOMETHING (...) ones, but assigning to $_ inside the loop messes that up somehow.

Comment: It's not because you're doing something in the loop. You only get told of the error if the `when` is successful (i.e. `$_ ~~ /b/` is true), and it just so happened to be successful that one time. Try `perl -E'$_="b"; for my $x ("b") { when (/b/) { } }'`. `for SOMETHING (...) { ... when ... }` is not allowed if `SOMETHING` isn't blank, `$_`, `my $_`, `our $_` or `state $_`.

Comment: Oh, why is it that `when` works one time but not after? Could you please explain the logic behind that? I'm just trying to understand the whole picture. 

I appreciate you taking the time to clarify things repeatedly, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ikegami spotted your actual problem. Regarding the other questions:

The two topicalizers are `for`/`foreach` and `given`. Other constructs that set `$_` (the topic variable), are not considered topicalizers (e.g. `map` or `grep`).

If you run a foreach-loop with an explicit loop variable, the loop isn't considered to be a topicalizer. Therefore,

```
for my $x (1..3) {
  local $_ = $x;
  say when 2;
}
```

will work for the first iteration, but then die (Can't "when" outside a topicalizer) once the `when` is exited.

The `given` is different in that it doesn't localize `$_`, but gives a lexical `$_`. That is, `given (@a) { foo; }` is similar to `{ my $_ = \@a; foo; }` (I think this might be fixed).