# How to mute that when and given are experimental in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am migrating an old toolchain to a new system and now I get plenty of notifications `given is experimental` or `when is experimental`.

```
$ perl -e 'use v5.10; given (12) { when (12) { print "Hello World" }}'
given is experimental at -e line 1.
when is experimental at -e line 1.
Hello World
```

I would like my new system to be fully compatible with the old one. By this I mean the exact same output.

Is there a way to mute these notifications without touching the oneliners nor the scripts?

Comment: Then what *would* you touch?

Comment: The executable I guess.

Comment: What "executable" -- is that compiled somehow? The one-liner you show will just print that. You can post-postprocess, filter these two things out of streams.

Comment: I mean the most stupid variation of this would be to make an alias of `perl` to `perl -e 'use v5.10; no warnings 'experimental::smartmatch'; $code = some_magic(); eval $code`.

Comment: That won't work if the code does `use warnings;` as it should.

Comment: That won't work if you launch a script with anything but just `perl` (with arguments).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all, note that smartmatching [*will*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16927024/589924) be removed in 5.42.

---

To use `given`+`when` without warnings, one needs the following:

```
# 5.10+
use feature qw( switch );
no if $] >= 5.018, warnings => qw( experimental::smartmatch );
```

or

```
# 5.18+
use feature qw( switch );
no warnings qw( experimental::smartmatch );
```

[experimental](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?experimental) provides a shortcut for those two statements.

```
use experimental qw( switch );
```

---

Finally, you ask how to add this to your programs without changing them (and presumably without changing Perl). That leaves monkeypatching.

I wouldn't recommend it. It's far easier to write a couple of one-liners to automatically fix up your programs that rewritting Perl's behaviour on the fly.

But if you want to go in that direction, the simplest solution is probably to write a `$SIG{__WARN__}` handler that filters out the undesired warnings.

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
   warn($_[0]) if $_[0] !~ /^(?:given|when) is experimental at /;
};
```

(Of course, that won't work if your program makes use of `$SIG{__WARN__}` already.)

To get it loaded without changing your programs or one-liners, all you have to do is place the patch in a module, and tell Perl to load the module as follows:

```
export PERL5OPT=-MMonkey::SilenceSwitchWarning
```

---

```
$ cat Monkey/SilenceSwitchWarning.pm
package Monkey::SilenceSwitchWarning;

use strict;
use warnings;

$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    warn($_[0]) if $_[0] !~ /^(?:given|when) is experimental at /;
};

1;

$ perl -e 'use v5.10; given (12) { when (12) { print "Hello World\n" }}'
given is experimental at -e line 1.
when is experimental at -e line 1.
Hello World

$ export PERL5OPT=-MMonkey::SilenceSwitchWarning

$ perl -e 'use v5.10; given (12) { when (12) { print "Hello World\n" }}'
Hello World
```

Comment: Arf! With this `perl -e '$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { warn("oops?") };` it doesn't work :( Do you know why?

Comment: What do you mean? It works for me (does absolutely nothing).

Comment: Sorry, use this instead: `$ perl -e '$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { warn("oops?") }; use v5.10; given(1) { when(1) {}}'
given is experimental at -e line 1.
when is experimental at -e line 1.`

Comment: It's a compile time warning, but you're only setting up the handler at runtime. Use `BEGIN`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141654/discussion-between-nowox-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 6):

```
no warnings 'experimental';
```

...works in version 5.22 at least.

Comment: Thanks.  It's weird though that eclipse was showing it as an error not a warning.  Neverthess, this worked for me.