# Perl unit testing: check if a string is an array

Tags: arrays, perl, unit-testing

I have this function that I want to test:

```
use constant NEXT => 'next';
use constant BACK => 'back';

sub getStringIDs {
    return [
        NEXT,
        BACK
    ];
}
```

I've tried to write the following test, but it fails:

```
subtest 'check if it contains BACK' => sub {
    use constant BACK => 'back';
    my $strings = $magicObject->getStringIDs();
    ok($strings =~ /BACK/);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have the constant defined in the test as well? What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @simbabque: I guess they're in different files and aren't exported correctly.

Comment: @DaveCross I have a feeling they want to use it in their regex. I don't think they even know they can export them.

Comment: @simbabque: Seems likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getStringIDs()` method returns an array reference.

The regex binding operator (`=~`) expects a string on its left-hand side. So it converts your array reference to a string. And a stringified array reference will look something like `ARRAY(0x1ff4a68)`. It doesn't give you any of the contents of the array.

You can get from your array reference (`$strings`) to an array by dereferencing it (`@$strings`). And you can stringify an array by putting it in double quotes (`"@$strings"`).

So you could do something like this:

```
ok("@$strings" =~ /BACK/);
```

But I suspect, you want word boundary markers in there:

```
ok("@$strings" =~ /\bBACK\b/);
```

And you might also prefer the `like()` testing function.

```
like("@$strings", qr[\bBACK\b], 'Strings array contains BACK');
```

**Update:** Another alternative is to use `grep` to check that one of your array elements is the string "BACK".

```
# Note: grep in scalar context returns the number of elements
# for which the block evaluated as 'true'. If we don't care how
# many elements are "BACK", we can just check that return value
# for truth with ok(). If we care that it's exactly 1, we should
# use is(..., 1) instead.

ok(grep { $_ eq 'BACK' } @$strings, 'Strings array contains BACK');
```

**Update 2:** Hmm... the fact that you're using constants here complicates this. Constants are subroutines and regexes are strings and subroutines aren't interpolated in strings.

Comment: May I ask you why you use `"@$strings"` and not simply `@$strings` (without quotes)?

Comment: And also, why do you use quotes in `$_ eq 'BACK'`

Comment: Using `$strings` runs all the elements together (`NEXTBACK`) whereas `"@strings"` puts spaces between the elements (`NEXT BACK`). That allows us to use `\b` to look for individual words. Otherwise, we could be in trouble if our array contained "FEB" and "ACK".

Comment: @just the quotes here in Dave's code relate to my comment on your question. When you use `m/BACK/` that's the string _BACK_, not the function call (constants are nothing more than functions in Perl). Perl can't interpolate function calls in strings.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `$magicObject->getStringIDs` is an array reference, not a string. It looks like the spirit of your test is that you want to check if at least one element in the array pattern matches `BACK`. The way to do this is to `grep` through the dereferenced array and check if there are a non-zero number of matches.

```
ok( grep(/BACK/,@$strings) != 0, 'contains BACK' );
```

---

At one time, the [smartmatch operator](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlop.pod#Smartmatch-Operator) promised to be a solution to this problem ...

```
ok( $strings ~~ /BACK/ )
```

but it has [fallen into disrepute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927024/perl-5-20-and-the-fate-of-smart-matching-and-given-when) and should be used with caution (and the `no warnings 'experimental::smartmatch'` pragma).

Answer (score 1):

The [`in` operator](http://p3rl.org/Syntax::Feature::In) is your friend.

```
use Test::More;
use syntax 'in';

use constant NEXT => 'next';
use constant BACK => 'back';

ok BACK |in| [NEXT, BACK], 'BACK is in the arrayref';
done_testing;
```

Comment: You should probably mention that they'll need to install the [syntax](https://metacpan.org/pod/syntax) and [Syntax::Feature::In](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Feature::In) modules.